# Using Self made class then already available (Rectangle contains ,overlaps method)

Tags: libgdx

i came across this codemany times

```
if (OverlapTester.pointInRectangle(playRegion, touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y)) {
     game.setTransitionScreen(game, new LevelScreen(game));
     return;
}
```

class ::

```
public class OverlapTester {
    public static boolean pointInRectangle (Rectangle r, float x, float y) {
         return r.x <= x && r.x + r.width >= x && r.y <= y && r.y + r.height >= y;
    }
}
```

i could not understand why this is done?? when libgdx already provides rectangle.contains(rec) and overlap method.

Answer (score 1):

There is really not need for this class.

Not only because Rectangle has a method to do the same, but because there is also [`Intersector`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Intersector.html) which offers this as well. `Intersector` has more though. It can be used for all kind of intersections and overlaps of other things, not only rectangles.

To keep your collision checks a bit more consistent, you should probably use the `Intersector` instead of the `Rectangle` methods, but it actually does the same.